# Properties of inverted function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I have a function $\eta(X)$ which is increasing and strictly concave.

I need to find the $X$ that solves for a given $\bar x$

$$ \eta(X)f(\bar x) - X = - G(\bar x)c$$

for some constant $c$ and some other strictly monotone functions $f, G$.

Since I couldn't find a nice closed form solution, I defined

$$h(X, \bar x) = \eta(X)f(\bar x) - X$$

and denote by $$h^X(Z, \bar x) = \{X: h(X, \bar x) = Z\}$$

the inverse of $h$ w.r.t. its first input. Due to the properties of $\eta$ and $f$, we know that $h^X$ is single valued over its domain.

Then, the solution to the first equation is given by

$$X = h^X(-G(\bar x)c, \bar x)$$

First: Was this so far correct? My mathematical background is weak, perhaps there is more standard notation for what I am doing?

To continue, I would like to compute some properties of $h^X$, most importantly, its first and second total derivative w.r.t. $\bar x$. How could I proceed?